# Application of cup-product for Leibniz cohomology

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, cup-product, leibniz-algebras

In 1995, Loday introduced a cup-product operation on the graded cohomology of Leibniz algebra and showed that the cup-product operation satisfies the graded Zinbiel relation.
 My question is how this cup-product is useful? 
In other words, can someone provide me some nice applications of this cup-product in Leibniz algebra world?